# JSP Tag Library to Add To Collection

Tags: jsp

I've got a JSP page which builds a list of Strings.  You can add to the list and clear the list.  I've got a scriptlet at the top of the page which interprets the submit action (add vs clear) and actually performs the action.  Is there any way to reduce the scriptlet code even further?  Would I need to create a custom tag?   Here is the code:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:useBean id="users" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="session"/>
<%
    String action = request.getParameter("action");

    if ("Clear".equals(action)) {
        users.clear();
    } else {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");

        if (name != null && !name.isEmpty()) {
            users.add(name);
        }
    }
%>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>User List</title>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <h1>User List</h1>
        <form method="post" action="Tag.jsp">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add" name="action"/>
            <c:if test="${not users.isEmpty()}">
                <input type="submit" value="Clear" name="action"/>
            </c:if>
        </form>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
                <li>${user}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Depending on how simple your app will be, you should probably think about using an MVC pattern and decoupling your controller (the add/clear logic) from your view (the JSP). I would never write scriptlet in a JSP because you lose a lot of a good Java IDE's assistance / error checking.

Comment: Yeah, scriptlets are what I'm trying to avoid.  Moving the controller logic elsewhere sounds good.  Should I put it in a Servlet?  Maybe a custom tag?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and moved the logic to a Servlet, which acts as the controller.  This seems to make more sense than a custom tag.

Comment: Bravo! For others stubmling on the question, check http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info how to get started with servlets.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link; it has really good information about Servlets!

Answer (score 0):

there are no standard jstl taglibs for this. You would have to create your own taglib, or google for for another solution.

Check out the standard jstl taglib here:http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html

Comment: Yeah, I had browsed the standard tag lib docs and didn't find anything for adding items to a collection.  The closest thing I found was the c:set tag.  I'm starting to think that creating a Servlet to be the controller would be the cleanest solution however.